# escape character for shoes in ruby

Tags: ruby, shoes

So I'm attempting to print a show an image of a url using the 'image' command in shoes. The issue is that my url contains % characters. This would not be an issue most of the time since I could just escape it but Shoes does not behave like I would expect it to. I've looked through the manual and other sources from Shoes but none seem to mention how to print use special characters.

Essentially right now alert yields...

```
alert "%D"  --> 2743522352

alert "\%D" --> 3439909232
```

but what I really want is

```
alert "%D"  -->%D
```

how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce this problem on red shoes. But I guess, to solve the problem, you should use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
alert '%D'  -->%D
```

Because in ruby, single quotes escape everything inside it.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but I'm still having an issue when I run alert '%D'. Now the value being returned is 2313736304. This makes absolutely no sense to me...

Comment: This is strange. Could you please tell me which shoes are you using? I am using Red shoes and I am not able to reproduce this problem.